# Find specific word in input file and read the data from next row in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input File:

```
32535
1243
1q332|2
EOH
CUST_ID|CUST_NAME|ORDER_NO|ORDER_ITEM
1|TAM|222|ORANGE
2|AAM|322|APPLE
```

```
output
CUST_ID|CUST_NAME|ORDER_NO|ORDER_ITEM
1|TAM|222|ORANGE
2|AAM|322|APPLE
```

Mentioned above the input and output. I want to read input file, if found 'EOH' word in input file and convert to Dataframe from next line. Before 'EOH' rows should be ignored. Output format is given above.
sometime few rows may be added before 'EOH'.Need to pickup based on 'EOH' word.
Please share Pyspark code.

Comment: The schema is always CUST_ID | CUST_NAME | ORDER_NO | ORDER_ITEM?

Comment: yes. Schema will  always be same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best approach, but here is:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (spark
      .read
      .format('csv')
      .option('delimiter', '|')
      .schema('CUST_ID string, CUST_NAME string, ORDER_NO integer, ORDER_ITEM STRING')
      .load(YOUR_PATH))

# Identifying which line is the header
df = (df
      .withColumn('id', f.monotonically_increasing_id())
      .withColumn('header', f.lag('CUST_ID', default=False).over(Window.orderBy('id')) == f.lit('EOH')))

# Collecting only header row to python context
header = df.where(f.col('header')).head()

# Removing all rows before header
df = (df
      .where(f.col('id') > f.lit(header.id))
      .drop('id', 'header'))

df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
|CUST_ID|CUST_NAME|ORDER_NO|ORDER_ITEM|
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
|      1|      TAM|     222|    ORANGE|
|      2|      AAM|     322|     APPLE|
+-------+---------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If the schema is fixed as in the comment, you can pass them into [`from_csv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_csv)

```py
schema = """
    CUST_ID INT,
    CUST_NAME STRING,
    ORDER_NO INT,
    ORDER_ITEM STRING
"""

# if you know for sure all fields are not null then
(df
    .withColumn('value', F.from_csv('value', schema, {'sep': '|'}))
    .select('value.*')
    .where(
        F.col('CUST_ID').isNotNull() &
        F.col('CUST_NAME').isNotNull() &
        F.col('ORDER_NO').isNotNull() &
        F.col('ORDER_ITEM').isNotNull()
    )
    .show(10, False)
)

# if you unsure about the nulls, you can filter them before processing (or there are many other options)
(df
    .withColumn('tmp', F.size(F.split('value', '\|')))
    .where((F.col('tmp') == 4) & (~F.col('value').startswith('CUST_ID')))
    .withColumn('value', F.from_csv('value', schema, {'sep': '|'}))
    .select('value.*')
    .show(10, False)
)

# +-------+---------+--------+----------+
# |CUST_ID|CUST_NAME|ORDER_NO|ORDER_ITEM|
# +-------+---------+--------+----------+
# |1      |TAM      |222     |ORANGE    |
# |2      |AAM      |322     |APPLE     |
# +-------+---------+--------+----------+
```